# How do i ignore rows with unique string while parsing a csv file in ruby

Tags: ruby, csv, parsing

i want to ignore ALL

```
TopLevel, Result,,,,,,,,
AddHost,10.1.3.1,,,,,,,,
```

and

```
Flush,,,,,,,,,
AddHost,10.1.3.4,,,,,,,,
```

from

```
TopLevel, Result,,,,,,,,
AddHost,10.1.3.1,,,,,,,,
Add,10.1.3.1,43172
Add,10.1.3.1,44172
Add,10.1.3.1,4172
Add,10.1.3.1,432
Add,10.1.3.1,435472
Flush,,,,,,,,,
AddHost,10.1.3.4,,,,,,,,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the contents of the CSV file:

```
s = "TopLevel, Result,,,,,,,,
AddHost,10.1.3.1,,,,,,,,
Add,10.1.3.1,43172
Add,10.1.3.1,44172
Add,10.1.3.1,4172
Add,10.1.3.1,432
Add,10.1.3.1,435472
Flush,,,,,,,,,
AddHost,10.1.3.4,,,,,,,,
"
```

gsub will remove the offending lines:

```
s = s.gsub(/TopLevel, Result,,,,,,,,\nAddHost,10.1.3.1,,,,,,,,\n/, '')
s = s.gsub(/Flush,,,,,,,,,\nAddHost,10.1.3.4,,,,,,,,\n/, '')
puts s
# => Add,10.1.3.1,43172
# => Add,10.1.3.1,44172
# => Add,10.1.3.1,4172
# => Add,10.1.3.1,432
# => Add,10.1.3.1,435472
```

You may want regular expressions less specific than that.  For example, if you want to remove ANY AddHost line following a TopLevel line, then the first regexp would be:

```
/TopLevel, Result,,,,,,,,\nAddHost.*\n/
```

When gsub is done munching on the file, pass the results to the CSV parser as normal.

Comment: Or, even better, run the CSV parser *first* and then operate on the parsed data.

Comment: Hi Wayne, 
Thanks for your response, i am new to Ruby , and trying to use 

#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'rubygems'
require 'faster_csv'

     FasterCSV.foreach("HOUND-1.csv", :quote_char => '"', :col_sep =>',', :row_sep =>:auto) do |row|
       puts row[0]
       break
     end

not sure HOW i woudl use the regex and substrings to ignore the offending lines